# Prevent hyphenation for words not in dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, spell-check

When enabling hyphenation, *Microsoft Word* also hyphenates terms it does not know, e.g. names, words in CamelCase.

These hyphenations are often terribly wrong ("SeqTrig" is hypenated as Se - qTrig")

Can I prevent hyphenation for all words that are *not* in the dictionary for the current language, or for all words that are on the spellcheck ignore list?

I am looking for a solution that works even if the document is opened on another pc.

I know I can manually select a word and disable spellchecking, and I could automate that for all occurrences of that word by search & replace.

But having such mixed invisible formatting within the same paragraph is cumbersome and the formatting may "leak" to other words, if I later edit the paragraph.

Comment: Don't use automatic hyphenation and do it manually, that would be the easiest, most portable way.

Comment: Obviously if I disable automatic hyphenation entirely, I won't have any wrongly hyphenated words. I was hoping for a slightly less intrusive solution tough. Currently I am editing a 100 page document, which will frequently be updated, and manual hyphenation is not feasible.

Comment: From what I can tell you don't have much of a choice. You might use [non-breaking hyphens](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d) and spaces in some cases but other than that changing the wording accordingly seems to be your best option. In addition even in a hundred page document it's not all just one paragraph (hopefully) so changes shouldn't really affect other paragraphs that much. Otherwise using something like latex might be more suitable but way more complex as well.